# Parse.com daily email sent based on data

Tags: parse-platform, mandrill, mailgun

I looking into the possibility of using Parse.com for a HTML5 Mobile app. The App will be simple enough although I will need to send a daily email to 2 different addresses based on the data recorded that day. I understand you can send emails via Mandrill/Mailgun APIs though they seem very basic do these API supports such complication.

Sorry I'm a Parse newbie on this

Thanx in advance

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: How do I send a daily email to 2 different addresses based on the data recorded that day?

Answer (score 0):

The ability to send a daily email is simple enough, just use a Cloud Code job and use one of the Cloud Modules for mail.

The issue of how you visualise your data and put that into an email might be trickier. You'll need to be able to either generate an image or turn the output into HTML, or just redirect them to some page on your site that shows the data.

Comment: I would need to turn the data into HTML(Or probably even better but less likely embed a CSV).  What it seems from Parse docs (https://parse.com/docs/cloud_modules_guide) is that you can only send transactional emails i.e. replying to a user signing up. Which is not what I'm after. Hopefully I'm wrong as it would save alot of time to set this up in Parse

Comment: Mailgun looks like a better match for what you want, https://parse.com/docs/cloud_modules_guide#mailgun